# Keep drop down menu open after hover (CSS)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I have created a horizontal menu that when you hover an item, a drop down menu appears. This is all fine. However, when you leave the menu item (to use the drop down) the drop down disappears. I understand that this is because you are no longer hovering it, but how do I solve this? Note: I don't want the drop down menu directly below it, I want a reasonable gap between the menu item and drop down (as I have it at the moment). Thanks.

HTML

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#top-anchor"><div id="logo"></div></a>
        <nav class="header-menu">
            <a href="index.html" class="header-menu-item">ABOUT</a>
                <div class="about-dropdown">
                    <a href="index.html#core-services-anchor">CORE SERVICES</a>
                    <a href="index.html#atandl-anchor">AT&amp;L</a>
                    <a href="index.html#hseq-anchor">HSEQ</a>
                    <a href="index.html#clients-anchor">CLIENTS</a>
                    <a href="index.html#contact-anchor">CONTACT</a>
                </div>
            <a href="services.html" class="header-menu-item">SERVICES</a>
            <a href="facilities.html" class="header-menu-item">FACILITIES</a>
            <a href="#map-anchor" class="header-menu-item">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="hamburger"></div>
        <!--<div id="box-shadow-menu"></div>-->
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  line-height: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  transform: translateX(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

header .container {
  width: 1440px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 0.75px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

#logo {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 27px;
  background-image: url(../images/logo_white.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

nav.header-menu {
  float: right;
  height: 96px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.header-menu-item {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 96px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  transition: 0.55s;
}

.toggle {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.current {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  z-index: 3000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.about-dropdown a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 28px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.header-menu-item:hover + .about-dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

[image: Drop Down Menu]

Comment: Do you want it to stay open if you hover over the Dropdown children or even if you dont hover anything anymore?

Comment: I can't get this working in a fiddle, but my guess is that your dropdown that shows needs a hover on it too to display block.

Comment: Would it be ok for you to use JavaScript/Jquery?

Comment: @WasteD Just if you hover the children. I just want it to act like a normal hover drop down menu but the gap between the menu item and the drop down is causing an issue.

Comment: @YannickHuber That would be okay, but just to let you know I haven't learned any yet so my knowledge is almost non-existent.

Comment: @Gezzasa I'm not sure if this will help as I think it is the gap inbetween them that is the problem.

Comment: You said that the gap is a Problem cant you just remove the gap?

Comment: @WasteD The gap is required. I have added a screenshot to show you what it looks like.

Comment: What if you try to add an invisible element and then add the `:hover` css to it?

Comment: @WasteD I will try that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: again, hard to test without a working fiddle. On the 'a' tag, add a height or padding-bottom to it on hover. Your 'a' tag might need to be positioned absolute so that its height won't affect the height of your header.

Comment: @Gezzasa That worked perfectly! Just added bottom padding. Simple as that. If you want to add it as an answer I will choose it. Thanks!

I want the drop down to appear slower so I added transition but it isn't working, why is this?

Comment: @ColinStewart Glad it worked for you. I've added it as an answer now :). Go read up about transition. I'm not experienced enough in it to be able to help. You can have a look at this link. It helped me. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition-timing-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the 'a' tag, add a height or padding-bottom to it on hover. Your 'a' tag might need to be positioned absolute so that its height won't affect the height of your header.

Something like the below

```
.about-dropdown a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 30px; /*height dependent on the gap you want to fill*/
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! By adding padding-bottom I solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I could not get your example to work. I did create a little [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f2mcag3s/) of a CSS only solution to your problem.

It allows users to trigger the submenu by hovering the menu item. They can then keep the submenu visible by hovering it. When their cursor leaves the submenu, the submenu will be hidden after some specified delay, I chose 1 second in my demo. If users hover the submenu again within this delay, the submenu is not hidden. This allows users not only to move their cursor from the menu item to the submenu, but also makes it so that the submenu is not hidden immediately when users accidentally move their cursor to the left or right of the submenu.

```css
.trigger {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;

  background: #4863a0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  
  /* hide element for now */
  max-height: 0; overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* make submenu not hoverable when opacity transition finished,
   * do this instantaneously */
  transition: max-height 0s 1.5s,
              /* hide the submenu after 1 second, in 400ms */
              opacity .4s 1s;
  
  /* prevent users from showing submenu when hovering hidden element */
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* sub elements can be hovered */
.sub > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

/* show submenu when trigger or menu itself is hovered */
.sub:hover,
.trigger:hover .sub {
  max-height: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

/* give items some spacing */
.item:not(:last-child) {
  padding: 10px 10px 5px;
}
.item:last-child {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">HOVER ME
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to (ab)use CSS [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). We hide the submenu completely and set a transition that is delayed. Then, when hovered, we set the delay to zero. What this will do is show the submenu immediately, but hide it only after some delay. This sort of works, but now the submenu can be shown when users hover the hidden element. To prevent this, we make the submenu have no height (`max-height: 0`) and hide its sub elements (`overflow: hidden`). Browsers may now still decide to trigger the hover element, so we make sure they do not by also setting `pointer-events: none`. All of this should also be delayed, hence the transition on `max-height`. Finally, we make it so that the submenu can actually be hovered when it is shown by setting `pointer-events: auto` for the elements in it. Unfortunately, it is not possible to transition to `max-height: none`, so we specify some very large value, I used `500px` in the demo.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It clearly works, so that's god – but another answer was a lot simpler for me.

Comment: No problem. I do want to mention that one advantage of my solution is that users can move their cursor anywhere and as long as they get back to the submenu quickly enough, it will remain visible. Using the `padding`, or adding some other element, means that users cannot move their cursor out of the strip between the menu item and the submenu.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Can you elaborate, @abc? It seems to work for me still in the snippet (Chrome + Firefox).