# Hover submenu doesn't stay opened

Tags: html, css

I made full width dropdown submenu. the problem is that submenu disappears when I try to move mouse from mainlist to submenu. Also, transition on submenu is not applied. Code I wrote is at down below. Please check it and correct it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
li,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.list>li:hover ul {
  display: list-item;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list>li:hover>a {
  color: red;
}

.sub_list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.sub_list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.sub_list li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">list-1</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">list-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list-4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list-5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to make submenu stay visible when mouse is on whole area of submenu div(100% width of screen).

please help
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep drop down menu open after hover (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154599/keep-drop-down-menu-open-after-hover-css)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the problem regarding margin/padding/positioning addressed in other answers, the transition wouldn't work because you can't transition from `display: none;` to another state or vice versa. Instead, solely rely on `opacity` and add the `pointer-events` property so that the submenu will not itself trigger the hover or overlay any other content when it's hidden.

Here's the fully working code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul, li, a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list > li:hover ul {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list > li:hover > a {
  color: red;
}

.sub_list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sub_list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.sub_list li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">list-1</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">list-2</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">list-3</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">list-4</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">list-5</a>
      <ul class="sub_list">
        <li><a href="#">sublist-a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublist-c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rboPLE
This is what i changed:

```
  .list li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px; // this line was margin: 20px; before
    }
```

When trying to reach the submenu you left the `.list li` item because it had a margin. With Padding the space belongs to the element and its still hovered when you move the mouse to submenu.

I colored the example in the link above so you can see the elements boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect but minor issues is there.

use this css code:

```
.sub_list {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-property: opacity, margin-top, visibility;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list > li:hover ul {
    margin-top:0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

use this code its work perfect transition effect and dropdown submenu issues is solved.

Answer (score 0):

simple use `opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;` and when hover on li tag change it to  `opacity: 1; visibility: visible; pointer-events: all;`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1f2024;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
header nav ul li a i {
  margin-left: 9px;
}
header nav ul li ul.dropdown {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
header nav ul li ul.dropdown li {
  padding: 5px 30px 0px 2px;
}
header nav ul li ul.dropdown li a {
  height: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
header nav ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 1<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 3<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```