# How to keep drop-down open after hover (only with css)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I've created a horizontal menu that when you hover over an item, a drop-down menu appears. This is ok. But when you leave the menu item (to use the drop-down) the drop-down disappears. I understand that this is because you are no longer hovering over it, but how do I solve this? I want the drop-down menu directly below it, I haven't programmed the dropdown position yet but it is anyway next to the button so I don't know what can I do to make it work, Thanks.
Note: It's also important to keep the code responsive :)

I've tried this:

```
#nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros, #dropdown-nosotros:hover {
display: block;
}
```

and this:

```
#dropdown-nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros {
    display: block;
}
```

What I'm expecting is to keep the drop-down menu open when someone wants to click a button inside the drop-down menu.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htlm>
    <header>
        <link href="styleprueba.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </header>
    <body>
        
        <button class="main-menu-button" id="nosotros">Nosotros</button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-nosotros">
                <h2 class="dropdown-title">Nosotros</h2>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Bienvenidos</button>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Misión y Visión</button>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Próximamente</button>
                <img src="">
            </div>
        
    </body>
</htlm>
```

CSS

```
#nosotros {
    position: fixed;
    top: 7%;
    right: 52%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.main-menu-button {
    font-family: lorimer-no-2, sans-serif;
    font-style: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.main-menu-second-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.main-menu-second-button:hover {
    color: aquamarine;
}
    
#nosotros + #dropdown-nosotros {
    display: none;
}

#nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros, #dropdown-nosotros:hover {
display: block;
}

#dropdown-nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need Javascript for this . That said, have you tried `:active`? This would be after a click on the drop-down.

Comment: thanks for answering :), you mean #dropdown-nosotros:active {
 display: block;
} ?

Comment: Yes

Comment: it doesn't work :( I believe it's something blocking the action but idk what could it be

Comment: Yeah `:active` is on desktop only at the time you have a `mousedown`. On mobile it is sometimes differently.

Comment: oh I can't use a mousedown because the button is going to redirect to another page and the dropdown needs to be open only with the hover over the button

Comment: Do you mean a `parent-selector`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: no, I mean the button #Nosotros is going to open a page, and when this button is hovered is going to be displayed the drop down menu

Comment: Hmm, what is the behavior you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154599/keep-drop-down-menu-open-after-hover-css here is a post that could help you.  

To make your code more readable:

Why do you need `id=nosotros & class=main-menu-button`? Choose one, because in the beginning it is confusing - style same element only in one place it will be a lot better, and that will not change the implementation (that is regarding your css file) :)

Comment: the idea is to get a behavior similar to the menu of the page of United Nations https://www.un.org/en/

Comment: You need a common parent for that to work. The `:hover` should be on that parent. Also, don't use `<button>` if what you need is an anchor - and vice versa.

Comment: @ApnikaPanika thanks for answering, I saw that post and those answers weren't suitable because the problem in my case isn't because the distance between my button and the drop down element

Comment: Essentially you need a wrapper element to contain both the menu item and its drop-down contents, and apply your `:hover` styles to this wrapper element. Just follow [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) from W3Schools.

Comment: But then the problem is to keep the measures of the button and its drop-down responsive because the parent element becomes the 100% and if this button is in % related to the father element, it will make the button move when the drop-down is open and the width of the button wouldn't be responsive to the screen measures, also the problem wouldn't be fixed because it isn't caused because of the lake of a wrapper element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized how to fix it!, what I did was to change the `position` to `static`, and then to keep the original design, I put margins in % so the website is responsive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htlm>
    <style>
        #nosotros {
        position: static;
        margin: 2% 0 0 40%;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        font-family: lorimer-no-2, sans-serif;
        font-style: black;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    #dropdown-nosotros {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        color: blue;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%
    }

    .main-menu-second-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: black;
        border-color: transparent;
    }

    .main-menu-second-button:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

    #nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros,
    #dropdown-nosotros:hover {
        display: block;
    }

    </style>
  <body>
        
        <button id="nosotros">Nosotros</button>

         <div id="dropdown-nosotros">
             <h2 class="dropdown-title">Nosotros</h2>
             <button class="main-menu-second-button">Bienvenidos</button>
             <button class="main-menu-second-button">Misión y Visión</button>
             <button class="main-menu-second-button">Próximamente</button>
             <img src="">
         </div>
        
  </body>
</htlm>
```

Comment: Actualy it Is not working. Everything élément default position is static. It is just that there is non Hover state on small screen it is touchscreen

Comment: So what is the equivalent of the Hover State on a touchscreen? To make a query for the mobile version

Comment: It is touchscreen when available on small screen devices. On desktops your dropdown will still appear and disappear on hover

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work:

```
<style>
    #nosotros {
    position: fixed;
    top: 7%;
    right: 52%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.main-menu-button {
    font-family: lorimer-no-2, sans-serif;
    font-style: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: blue;
    display: none;  /* It will nitially hide the dropdown */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* This will adjust the top position according to your design */
    right: 0; /* This will align the dropdown with the button */
    width: 100%; /* This will make the dropdown full width kindly adjust according to your need */
}
.main-menu-second-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.main-menu-second-button:hover {
    color: aquamarine;
}

#nosotros:hover + .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htlm>
    <header>
        <link href="styleprueba.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </header>
    <body>
        
        <button class="main-menu-button" id="nosotros">Nosotros</button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-nosotros">
                <h2 class="dropdown-title">Nosotros</h2>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Bienvenidos</button>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Misión y Visión</button>
                <button class="main-menu-second-button">Próximamente</button>
                <img src="">
            </div>
        
    </body>
</htlm>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and time, I've just tried and sadly it didn't work

Comment: kindly briefly describe what you want, as your question is unclear

Comment: I'm hoping to build a drop downing menu like the one on the United Nations page https://www.un.org/en/ but with only html and css

Answer (score 0):

in the exemple you first tried can you change it and try again :

```css
#nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros,
#dropdown-nosotros:hover {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}

#nosotros:hover + #dropdown-nosotros .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: sorry for my late reply and thank you for answering, I put your code in the last part in the <style>, and when I ran it still kept closing after stopping hovering the button, I've also put the z-index in minus one so now the drop-down is displaying in the back of the button